# Create nested Transaction in mssql using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am trying to create nested transactions in NodeJs using MSSQL NPM. I am using following code block

```
var sqlModule = require("mssql");

var sqlManagerClass = require("./sqlManager.js");

var sql = new sqlManagerClass(sqlModule);
sql.setConfig({
  user: "dbo",
  password: "***********",
  server: "127.0.0.1",
  database: "dbname",
  requestTimeout: 120000,
});

sql.beginTransaction(function (transaction) {
  if (transaction == null) {
    callback("Unable to Start Transaction", null);
    return;
  }
  sql.beginTransaction(function (newTransaction) {
    if (newTransaction == null) {
      callback("Unable to Start newTransaction", null);
      return;
    }
    sql.execute(
      "dbname.dbo.insert_dest",
      [],
      [],
      function (err, results) {
        console.log(results);
        newTransaction.commit(function (err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
          sql.execute("dbname.dbo.select_dest", [], [], function (
            err,
            results2
          ) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              return;
            }
            console.log(results2);
            transaction.rollback(function (rollBackErr) {
              if (rollBackErr) {
                console.log(rollBackErr);
              }
              sql.execute("dbname.dbo.select_dest", [], [], function (
                err,
                results2
              ) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  return;
                }
                console.log(results2);
                console.log('end')
              });
            });
          });
        });
      },
      newTransaction
    );
  });
});
```

creating transaction

```
this.beginTransaction = function(callback, transaction) {


        // if the optional transaction argument is passed in, we are already working with a transation, just return it
        if (typeof transaction !== "undefined") {
            callback(transaction);
            return;
        }
        self.connectSql(function(err) {

            var transaction = new self.sql.Transaction(self.connection);

            transaction.begin(function(err) {
                // ... error checks 
                if (err) {
                    self.log("SQLManager - Error Beginning Transaction " + err);
                    callback(null);
                }

                // callback with the transaction handler
                callback(transaction);
            });
        });
    }
```

I have to create 2 transactions so that I can start a transaction and perform a set of operations on different stored procedures id any thing goes wrong I can revert back to my original state using the first transaction.

In short I am trying to achieve something like following SQL code

```
BEGIN TRAN T1;
BEGIN TRAN M2
INSERT INTO dbo.dest
(
    Code,
    Text,
    Type
)
VALUES
(   'l', -- Code - varchar(50)
    'Love', -- Text - varchar(50)
    2   -- Type - int
    )
COMMIT TRAN M2
// I am calling another Sp which is similar to this
SELECT * FROM dbo.dest
//validation the code 
//if error
ROLLBACK TRAN T1
```

My question is how can I create nested transaction so that I can revert back entire transaction if any error occur after the first transaction complete. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First read this

[A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/)

To see if SQL Server "nested transactions" or savepoints are really going to help you.

Then you'll probably have to handle this all yourself by issuing the transaction control statements using `sql.execute()`  eg:

```
sql.execute("begin transaction");
//something that works
sql.execute("save transaction MyTran");
//something that fails
sql.execute("rollback transaction MyTran");
sql.execute("commit transaction");
```

> how can I create nested transaction so that I can revert back entire transaction if any error occur after the first transaction complete

What you have will do that.  Nested transactions are not real, so calling

```
begin tran
...
begin tran --<-- @@trancount += 1, but nothing else really happens
...
commit tran --<--nothing is really commited yet. @@trancount -= 1
...
rollback tran --<-- all work is rolled back
```

Comment: Can I Rollback entire transaction with out rolling back the saved transaction??

Comment: No. That would be an "autonomous transaction", and SQL Server doesn't support that.  Perhaps you could add to your question some additional information about what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: In short I am trying to achievesomething like this BEGIN TRAN T1;
BEGIN TRAN M2
INSERT INTO dbo.dest
(
    Code,
    Text,
    Type
)
VALUES
(   'l', -- Code - varchar(50)
    'Love', -- Text - varchar(50)
    2   -- Type - int
    )
COMMIT TRAN M2
// I am calling another Sp which is similar to this
SELECT * FROM dbo.dest
//validation the code 
//if error
ROLLBACK TRAN T1

Comment: If I have multiple transactions, which are doing operations on same db, will it save them as well or it will apply the save point on current transaction.

Comment: There is only ever one transaction per session.